# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - React

Tags: reactjs

I have two components `ResultsList` and `MyCard`.

The first compoennts, uses a `.map` functions to iterate through a `results["my_results"]` which is an array of array from axios response.

The second component simply display the results.

However, I am getting the error:

> > Maximum call stack size exceeded

Looking into similar questions, it seems that I am calling recursively something. However, I am not understand where.

The website works as follow:

On a single page the user types his query, when he presses the search button, the results appears below the search bar. Therefore, I am calling `ResultsList` inside my form `Searchform`

**Searchform**

```
function Searchform() {
  IT HANDLES THE QUERY
  return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       IT HANDLES THE QUERY
    </form>
    <ResultsList results={results} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ResultsList component**

```
function ResultsList({results}) { // destructuring props to get results     
  if (results[0] === "myemptyinitiallist") {
    return null
  } else {
    return(
      <div className="results-list">
        <div>
          {results["my_results"][0].map(function(result, index){
            return (
              <MyCard key={index} result={result}/>
              )})}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }

}


export default ResultsList;
```

**MyCard component**

```
function MyCard({result}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
         <a href={result[2]} target="_blank">{result[1]}</a>
        </Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
          Decided: {result[3]}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}


export default MyCard;
```

**results["my_results"]**

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling ResultList?

Comment: please post a complete snippet that shows how you render these components.

Comment: Are you sure your ResultsList component is not getting called recursively? Your 2 components look good to me. But not sure about where you are receiving data from API and not repeatedly calling the ResultList component.

Comment: I modified my answer. I think the problem is that I return in `my_results` more than 10000 results and they are displayed in the same page. Therefore it run outs of memory. Do you think that if I do pagination, it will solve it?